# Displaying embeded images on a picturebox matching selected listview item

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, imagelist

How can I display embedded images when the listView1 SelectedIndexChanged, I need to pull the image name based on the listview item and display it on the picturebox?
My code:

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        label1.Text = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text + " " +
                      textBox2.Text;

        var myimage = "_" + listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text;

        // new code tryout
        // When I try to do it like this Code runs fine 
        // but no image is displayed on picturebox
         object O = Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("myimage"); 

        pictureBox1.Image = (Image)O; 

        //no image displayed and no errors    

    }
    else
    {
        label1.Text = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `(Bitmap) WindowsFormApplication1.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("...");`

Comment: @ Loathing, thank you so much for your time! I tried this with no luck no image is displayed. Updated my original code.

Comment: Did you try `Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(myimage);` without quotes?

Comment: I was about to edit my post, that is the issue.. thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are confusing the string `"myimage"` with the content of `myimage` variable.

You should use the variable's content and not the string as the `GetObject` parameter:

```
object O = Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(myimage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact that I don't know how you did fill your ListView, I took the idea of yours and it works fine.  Here's a modified code  with a screenshot of the result :

[image]

```
private void View_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (View.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        object O = Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(View.SelectedItems[0].Text);

        PicBox.Image = (Image)O;
    }
}
```

Comment: `I took your code`.. I don't think so, this is not OP's code

Comment: In fact I really took the code and just changed the ListView name and the PictureBox.  Since I didn't have the entire solution I had to create one the way it was explained.  See even the comment is the same there.

Comment: Edited my answer so there's no doubt

Comment: No, the problem is that you are using `View.SelectedItems[0].Text` and the OP is using `"myimage"` and this is exactly what the OP is doing wrong. By the way, in Stack Overflow you shouldn't post a "is working on my pc" answer but a solution

Comment: Hi Tobia,

I can assure you that the intend was to explain a working solution not to do an exact replica of the OP code.  Hope this help understand.